# Android Studio App to send images without permission or buttons

Tags: android, image, wifi-direct

Is it possible to create an App which can receive images without using any permissions or buttons on the receiving device? I would like to show these images instantly on the device (device has no touchscreen so I can't accept any permissions). The device has only WiFi and no Bluetooth.

I was thinking about choosing a image from my smartphone, connect it to the target device, send it via WiFi-Direct(P2P) and display it on the device.

Is something like that possible? All the tutorials to sending/receiving images always have the issue that buttons or permissions are necessary.

Comment: If you keep the image data in memory and don't need to save it to the device, then the only permission you should need is `INTERNET`, which you don't have to ask the user for.

Comment: the problem with your question isn't that you're asking if it's possible, the problem is the follow-up which comes from that, which is `how` and that would be too broad :)

Comment: So there is a way to just display the image without saving it to the device storage? Like mirroring it from the smartphone to the target device? This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that simply if you set an `ImageView` that will load the image from an URL (for example). Could be your website or a share site that has a static link reference.
It could look like that:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Glide.with(this).load("https://your-image.png").into(imageView);
    }
```

Use this implemtation in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

And in the other `build.gradle` folder:

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Here is a example [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UFNT6MhIlA&ab_channel=Stevdza-San) written in `kotlin`.
And also the `glide` feature explained at [github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).